# PHP If condition with XML

Tags: php, xml, if-statement

I'm trying to build a PHP if expression.

In English, here's the conditions for the IF to be true:

Visbility < 5000m

OR

BKN/OVC < 1500ft

Now, the variables I have to play with are:

for Visibility: $visibility and for the BKN/OVC: it's a bit more complex.

This data is given in

```
$xml->data->METAR[0]->sky_condition
```

The data itself is pulled from XML file with the relevant information looking like this:

```
<sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="600"/>
<sky_condition sky_cover="SCT" cloud_base_ft_agl="1100"/>
```

Any ideas on how I could sort through the sky_condition->sky_cover for the relevant information and feed it through to the IF?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference with [this other question you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115762/getting-attributes-from-xml-in-php?rq=1)?

Comment: This specifically deals with one element in deciding whether one variable is true or not, based on information from the XML. The other question was basically outputting the data from the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the attributes of the XML with the array syntax instead of the arrow operator.

```
if((string)$xml->data->METAR[0]->sky_condition[0]['sky_cover']==='???') {

}
```

Was this your question?